# Changing username

Tags: support, display-names

My username was originally my nickname, which I was called by almost everyone.  Events have since happened, however.  That name is now an old name that reminds me of a part of my life I would rather not be reminded of.

Is it possible to change it?

Comment: You know, you don't have to tell us *why* you want to change your name.  Like I didn't tell anyone that I am a fugitive from the law for the murder of my wife who was killed by a one armed man.  ... wait ...